# manipulating time in python to be default 8 hours

Tags: python, date, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm working on a python flask project that has table named requests 
and it gets data or adds data in it
when a new request is submitted, the
 **current time**is recorded and when it's edited and status set to pending, current time at that time is recorded too in another column.
 i made a thread that runs in background to subtract current time from start time and pending time to check for time since request was submitted or pending. however , i need to modify it so that the day is from 08:00 to 16:00 and that's it and if current time is bigger  it's simply shifted to the next day's , except for Thursday it's shifted two days
example :

**if request is pending at Tuesday 15:00
and today is Wednesday and the time is now 08:30 the subtraction result should be only one and a half hour not 17:30 hours
and make sure to count Friday as holiday
i can try to make it with many conditions and add 16 hours to time but i believe there should be an easier solution. is there any ?**
this is the thread with the incomplete bad solution

```
def monitoring_loop():
    while True:
        #if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")=="15:59:59" or datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:#%S")=="12:30:00":
        session = DBSession()  
        UserRequests= session.query(Requests).filter(Requests.Status_Name!="Solved").all()     
        if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")>="08:00:00" and datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")<"15:59:59":
            currentTime=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print("Saving Changes Normally")
            datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            for req in UserRequests:
                if req.Status_Name=="Opened" :
                    c = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- datetime.strptime(str(req.Record_Created), datetimeFormat) 
                    req.OpenedToPending =c.total_seconds()/60
                    req.PendingToSolved =0
                    session.add(req)
                elif req.Status_Name=="Pending" :
                    p = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- datetime.strptime(str(req.FirstResponseAt), datetimeFormat)
                    req.PendingToSolved =p.total_seconds()/60
                    session.add(req)
        else:
            if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")>"16:00:00" and datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")<="23:59:59":
                currentTime=datetime.strptime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00")+timedelta(days=1)
                for req in UserRequests:
                    if req.Status_Name=="Opened" :
                        c = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- (datetime.strptime(str(req.Record_Created), datetimeFormat)+timedelta(hours=16)) 
                        req.OpenedToPending =c.total_seconds()/60
                        req.PendingToSolved =0
                        session.add(req)
                    elif req.Status_Name=="Pending" :
                        p = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- (datetime.strptime(str(req.FirstResponseAt), datetimeFormat)+timedelta(hours=16))
                        req.PendingToSolved =p.total_seconds()/60
                        session.add(req)
            elif datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")>"00:00:00" and datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")<"08:00:00":
                currentTime=datetime.strptime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00")
                for req in UserRequests:
                    if req.Status_Name=="Opened" :
                        c = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- (datetime.strptime(str(req.Record_Created), datetimeFormat)+timedelta(hours=16)) 
                        req.OpenedToPending =c.total_seconds()/60
                        req.PendingToSolved =0
                        session.add(req)
                    elif req.Status_Name=="Pending" :
                        p = datetime.strptime(currentTime, datetimeFormat)- (datetime.strptime(str(req.FirstResponseAt), datetimeFormat)+timedelta(hours=16))
                        req.PendingToSolved =p.total_seconds()/60
                        session.add(req)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic trick as such - but someone else has already thought about this and there is a module `businesstimedelta` that does what you want it to do:

```
import datetime
import businesstimedelta

workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(start_time=datetime.time(8),
                                        end_time=datetime.time(16),
                                        working_days=[0,1,2,3,6])

businesshours = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday])


d1 = datetime.datetime(2020,2,3,14,0,0)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2020,2,4,10,0,0)

d3 = datetime.datetime(2020,2,6,14,0,0)
d4 = datetime.datetime(2020,2,9,10,0,0)


print(businesshours.difference(d1,d2))
print(businesshours.difference(d3,d4))
```

This defines a working week so that work hours are 8-16 and it declares Friday and Saturday as days off. Then it does some calculations. d1 is a Monday, d2 Tuesday, d3 Thursday and d4 Sunday.

You can customise the working days as you wish, 0 appears to be Monday and 6 Sunday.

Comment: Perfect solution